# How do I make fully responsive SVGs in an android app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, svg, responsive-design

I am certain there is a way to make images(probably in **SVG** format) fully **responsive** to different screen sizes in an android application, but how is that achieved?

I've tried increasing the width and the height of an `ImageView` to, let's say, 400dp but it is still static and won't look as big on a tablet.

I am currently trying to make it work with a `ConstraintLayout` constraints but I can't quite figure it out. It stays centered, but I can't make it bigger.

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: If you question is you want your design component size follow user device, you can search on youtube or other website with keyword "Responsive design android studio" like this https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=responsive+design+android+studio

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to completely re-design my already existing app with some libraries and APIs...I am looking to make just the images a tiny bit more responsive.